# How I return multiple parameters using XML-RPC.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, xml-rpc

I am implementing in ASP.NET custom server protocol in XML RPC due to specification. I use library  XML-RPC.NET.

I got stuck on one method, because the specification of the custom protocol says that the method X has two output parameters (integer and boolen). How can I do that using C# and XML-RPC.NET?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XML-RPC response only has a single <param> return value. To return two values, as in your case, the return value would have to be a struct or array value.

Comment: Thnak you. I have found example you mention here http://xmlrpc-c.sourceforge.net/introspection.html. In spite there is <params> element in response, the value is return using array. I was confused by tu plural of params. I will try it.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question after long time. There are two possibilities.

1. return special type XmlRpcStruct (http://xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/javadoc/redstone/xmlrpc/XmlRpcStruct.html)
2. return Struct which have properties names like param names.